# Format for event.startdate in EKEvent Framework

Tags: iphone

I am accessing data from web service and i want display date with time in event.startdate which is coming from web service (time format is 7:55 AM Et) so, can any one tell me the solution for it.

B'cos our system format is GMT and it will not supported for this.Following is my code for it..

```
       date=[NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"%@",date);

    //NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];

    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSString *dateStart1 =detail.filedate;
    NSLog(@"%@",dateStart1);


    NSDate *dateStart =[formatter dateFromString:dateStart1];


    NSDate *dateEnd =[formatter dateFromString:dateStart1];

    event.startDate = dateStart;
```

Thanks,
Priyanka......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dateFormat in EKEvent Framework is, YYYY-MM-dd. So use,

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
```

Comment: thanx for u r reply i m using same but also i want to display time along with this date and the format is 7:55 AM ET so what what to do to get this time format with date..